# Find Average Of a key with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary e.g:

```
Jhon: 3, 4, 5
Mark: 5, 5, 5
Matthew: 7, 8 , 9
```

This is my code:

```
from statistics import mean
class1 = {}
for line in f:
            columns = line.split(":")
            if len(columns) == 2:
                names = columns[0]
                scores = columns[1].strip()
            else:
                pass
            if class1.get(names):
                class1[names].append(scores)
            else:
                class1[names] = list(scores)
```

I have already tried:

```
for k, v in class1.items()
   print("{} : {scores}".format(names , mean(scores)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

And I have also tried:

```
for k, v in class1.items():
   average = float(sum(v))/len(v)
for k, v in class1.items():
   print("{} : {}".format(names=k, average=v)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Onyeka/PycharmProjects/untitled/task3.py", line 59, in <module>
    print("{} : {scores}".format(names , mean(scores)))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\statistics.py", line 331, in mean
    T, total, count = _sum(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\statistics.py", line 161, in _sum
    for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\statistics.py", line 247, in _exact_ratio
    raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__))
TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
```

I want the output to be like this

```
   Jhon: 4
   Mark: 3
   Matthew: 8
```

Would it also be possible to  print these averages in order from highest to lowest?

Comment: `mean(scores)` should be `mean(v)`, and you're missing some parentheses. And `.format(names=k, average=v)` should jusst be `.format(v, average)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about some of what you've posted, including strange formatting for your dictionary, but I think I understand basically what you want.  This is how I solved it:

```
from statistics import mean

f = {'Jhon': [3, 4, 5], 'Mark': [5, 5, 5], 'Matthew': [7, 8 , 9]}
averages = {}
for key in f:
    averages[key] = int(mean(f[key]))

print(averages)
```

Output is:

```
{'Matthew': 8, 'Mark': 5, 'Jhon': 4}
```

Comment: I get: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Do you know what this means?

Comment: Sounds like somewhere in your code you're attempting to use a list as a key for a dictionary, which Python does not allow (because dictionary keys must be immutable).  The bit of code I quoted ran without error on my system, but it may be possible that a change to it, or some other part of your code may be causing that TypeError.